# Dynamic route prefix when the user's role is provided

Tags: laravel

```
Route::group([
    'namespace' => 'Admin',
    'middleware' => 'isAdmin',
    'prefix' => 'admin'
], function () {

    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index')->name('admin.home');
    Route::get('/profile', 'PagesController@profilePage')->name('admin.profiles');
    Route::get('/newsfeed/publish', 'PagesController@createNewsfeed')->name('admin.add-newsfeed');
    Route::get('/newsfeeds', 'PagesController@newsfeedsPage')->name('admin.newsfeeds.index');

});
```

w/ that code, I want to be redirected to admin/org/johndoe/ or admin/org/johndoe/profile if the user has role_id of 4 that's satisfied by this code in my login method

```
 switch(auth()->user()->role_id) {
            case 1 : return redirect()->route('students.dashboard'); break ;
            case 4 : return redirect()->route('admin.home'); break ; 
            case 6 : return redirect()->route('admin.home'); break ; 
            default : return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))->withErrors($error);
        }
```

please help me, I'm not really that good

Comment: So, what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the route::group and have the correct permission configured. you dont need to use the switch case to redirect it.

You can check [this out](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) to refer how to configure.
Hope this can help to fix your problems.